# would like the option to answer on hold questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, on-hold-questions

I was busy writing a long- ish answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097163/when-we-have-a-circle-in-euclidian-in-h-what-is-the-center-and-radius-of-this-c

but the question is on hold, 
and now I cannot post my answer.

(I guess it is just the waiting to become live queue )

I would like to be able that even while an question is on hold, it is possible to post answers.

I can agree that the answer will be hidden or so but just not be able to post an answer at all is I think to crude

(my answer is just to long to put in a comment)

Comment: No real reason why people shouldn't be able to post an answer if the only thing stopping them from doing so is typing speed (in the sense that if one could type fast enough, one would answer it before it got closed).

Comment: A few weeks ago, I'm in a similar situation. I temporarily place my answer into the [sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/59379), refer to it in a comment to the original question and wait for its author to response. Since there is no feedback, I remove the answer from sandbox.

Comment: The whole point of putting questions on-hold is to make it impossible to post answers to them.

Comment: FYI: Downvotes to your question in this context most likely signify disagreement, rather than "your question is bad."

Answer (score 16):

Wait and see if the OP returns to edit the question into something better. In the case where a couple days go by, and the OP has not returned (which is a possible option, seeing how it is an unregistered user), edit the question yourself, then request it to be reopened and post an answer.

Or, if you're not in the mood for waiting, post the question yourself written properly, and post the answer below. In this case, you should mention in the comments to that you did this because that such and such question was put on hold etc.

Comment: Hey Asaf -- similar situation has happened to me a couple of times. How can we request questions to be re-opened? Thanks

Comment: There is a thread on meta dedicated for this.